# python: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, staleelementreferenceexception

I am facing problem error below:

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I have to click value in table form to select the data and process to following steps.

These are my codes, and error line is the last one.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://tms.samil.com/ProjectMonitoring/ProjectActivityDetail")


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchHeadDiv']/button").click()


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='projectSearch']/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/a").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='projectSearch']/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
project_code_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='projectSearch']/div/div[1]/form/input")


project_list = '00575-01-011'
project_code_input.send_keys(project_list)
project_code_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='projectSearchGrid']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").click()
```

Comment: It seems you are not waiting for things to be executed. Try to wait or sleep after each click, especially the enter key.

Comment: That's why I write a code "driver.implicitly_wait(5)" in 2nd line. Isn't it proper code to wait?

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait() is the same as python sleep(). It only wait at that moment. Normally you need to wait after EACH action like click(),... in this example, you need to wait after hit enter key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried sleep() function, and problem solved.